# The directory is not writable by the Web process

Tags: yii2, centos, php7

Поставил на сервер nginx + php7.0-fpm+mysql, все работает, залил на сервер сайт и получаю ошибку:

**The directory is not writable by the Web process: /var/www/site.ru/web/assets**

Фреймворк Yii2, так понимаю ему не хватает прав для записи, в php www.conf стоят данные:

```
user = dogmar
group = dogmar
listen.owner = dogmar
listen.group = dogmar
listen.mode = 0777
```

**в nginx:**

```
user dogmar;
```

**В командной строке прописал:**

```
chown -R dogmar:dogmar /var/www/site.ru/web/assets
```

Пожалуйста подскажите, куда копать?

Comment: А у самой папки какие права доступа?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> chown -R dogmar:dogmar /var/www/site.ru/web/assets
> ```

если и после того, как вы сменили владельца каталога (и всего его содержимого), ошибка присутствует, вероятно, у каталога (и, возможно, содержимого) нет бита, разрешающего запись. добавьте его:

```
$ sudo chmod -R ug+w,o-w /var/www/site.ru/web/assets
```

- `ug+w` — добавить бит записи для владельца и его группы (*u*ser и *g*roup)
- `o-w` — убрать бит записи для всех остальных (*o*thers) — на всякий случай. не помешает.

Answer (score 0):

У меня тоже была такая проблема, но я решал ее через php init.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы видите на фото, таким образом даются права на запись папкам

```
  chmod 0777 backend/runtime
  chmod 0777 backend/web/assets
  chmod 0777 console/runtime
  chmod 0777 frontend/runtime
  chmod 0777 frontend/web/assets
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не используйте скриншоты вместо кода и сообщений об ошибках. [**Аргументация**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4692/199934). Спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

У папки assets должны быть права на запись, сделайте 
chmod 777 /var/www/site.ru/web/assets

Comment: плохой совет. **всем** не нужны права на запись. только владельцу. и, на всякий случай, группе: `$ sudo chmod ug+w,o-w /путь/к/каталогу`